# Datasets with high frequency measures of monetary policy shocks for the US

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy, data-request

I am looking for sources (datasets) with high frequency measures of monetary policy shocks for the US. For the Euro area I have found this, [MPD DATASET](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/annex/Dataset_EA-MPD.xlsx). I haven't found anything similar for the US. I have just  found the data from this paper [(Karadi Jarociński 2020)](https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/pol). Do you know any source that is updated periodically or a paper with more updated data?